# Javascript matrix determinant

Tags: javascript, html, matrix

A matrix determinant function doesn't work and I don't know why.It seems all right to  me.Could somebody please help me.

Html

```
<div id = "table1">
            <div class = "header">Wyznacznik [2x2]</div>
                <form id = "row1">
                    <input type = "text" class = "det1"/><!--first row-->
                    <input type = "text" class = "det1"/>
                </form>
                <form id = "row2">
                    <input type = "text" class = "det1"/><!-- second row-->
                    <input type = "text" class = "det1"/>
                </form>
            <div class = "count"><a href = "#" onclick="det('det1','caclValue2')">Wylicz</a></div>
                <input type = "text" id = "calcValue2"/>
            </div>
```

javascript

```
function det(className,outputId){
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
var determinant = 0; 
if(arr.length == 2){
determinant = (arr[0].value*arr[3].value) - (arr[1].value*arr[2].value);
}
else if(arr.length == 3){
determinant = (arr[0].value*((arr[4].value*arr[8].value) - (arr[5].value *     arr[7].value))) - 
(arr[1].value*((arr[3].value*arr[8].value) - (arr[5].value * arr[6].value))) +
(arr[2].value*((arr[3].value*arr[7].value) - (arr[4].value * arr[6].value))); 
}
document.getElementById(outputId).value = determinant;
return determinant;
}
```

EDIT!: if statement should have arr.length == 4 and else if arr.length == 9.

Answer (score 0):

You filter on the length of the array to be 2, but after that you try to access indices beyond that:

```
if(arr.length == 2){
    determinant = (arr[0].value*arr[3].value) - (arr[1].value*arr[2].value);
}
```

Same for the other if statement. Did you actually look at errors in your console?

Comment: the console gave me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null " erron on 11 line(document.getElementById(outputId).value).

Comment: That one is due to a typo. Change 'caclValue2' into 'calcValue2'.